# Reload ContentFinder when switch to other page

Tags: aem

I have custom contentfinder tab which accept the page path and on the basis on this fetch the assets from DAM, Now if i move to another page suppose from /en/home.html to /en/product.html, contentfinder still shows the record relevant to /en/home.html until I don't reload the whole page.

Is there any way to reload the contentfinder tab automatically when move to another page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to achieve: 
First way to place the below javascript code on top of the page hierarchy or the pages on which you want to reload content finder.

```
<script type="text/javascript">CQ.Ext.onReady(function() { CQ.WCM.getContentFinder().findByType("contentfindertab")[5].submitQueryBox.call(CQ.WCM.getContentFinder().findByType("contentfindertab")[5], this); }); </script>
```

What this code does ? :
The code CQ.WCM.getContentFinder(); fetches you the content finder window, findByType("contentfindertab") fetches all the content finder tabs as an array objects, since the pages is the 6th tab and based on array indexes the [5] value will give pages content finder tab.

The code submitQueryBox.call submits the query box of pages hence the results are refreshed.

Second way to achieve the same is to override default pages.js and in allowedPaths provide the paths for which the content finder need not be refreshed. If you see the OOTB pages.js it has allowedPaths as `"allowedPaths": [
        "/content/*",
        "/etc/scaffolding/*",
        "/etc/workflow/packages/*"
    ]`
When you navigate to any page the below code gets executed CQ.wcm.ContentFinder.loadContentWindow('tonavigationpath'); and it checks for the allowedPaths if it is included in the allowedPaths e.g. /content/* means anything url from /content/, the content finder does not gets reloaded else the content finder will get reloaded. Here by saying content finder gets reloaded I mean the content finder as a complete window and not the search results.

To understand more details refer to /libs/wcm/extensions/contentfinder/pages.js in crx.

Hope this helps. Please accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: Thnaks, I applied the js code Ist way to /apps/geometrixx-media/components/page/media-home/content.jsp file, but when i move from /content/geometrixx-media/en/entertainment.html to /content/geometrixx-media/en/gadgets.html CF doesn't refresh or reload.

Comment: I have updated my answer with new code and I have pasted this code in /apps/geometrixx-media/global.jsp this code is similar to the earlier code only difference is in the way we were fetching the page content finder tab.  The previous one fetches by id not sure why it didn't worked usually it does. Also note this will only refresh the results in the pages tab provided its selected. Please double check.

Comment: No, CF still showing record relevant to past page. Actully this will work if contentfinder will reload as only then it can get new url of the page in its js. Refresh will not work as it keep point to the same location, but in my case if page will change the location of assets will change, this location i am passing to the viewjson server as window.location.href (request param)

Comment: Can you please let me know more on your implementation like you have a  custom Servlet which takes window.location.href and returns the results or you are passing that as an argument to /bin/wcm/contentfinder/page/view.json/content ? Also you mentioned about different assets to be displayed based on the page location so   are those different assets comes in images,movies content findertab ? The code I have pasted will in general just refresh the results in the pages content findertab.

Comment: I had this implementation wherein we want to search the pages with different params e.g. you have to search pages based on a particular keyword or tag or location, for which we have overriden the pages content finder tab in which the searchbox have different xtypes like textfield, tag field and pathfield etc. and based on the value selection and submitting the values by clicking submit button in query box the values are submitted to a custom servlet which provides required json. Similar such idea you may apply by keeping hidden field in the query box which takes arguments as window.location.